# Unbind port bound by `StreamSocketListener`

Tags: c++, windows-10, uwp

While testing [my server](https://github.com/anhoavu/BackgroundServer) using `StreamSocketListener` (see the README for some information about the API), I run into problem when the host process/app is killed but the port is not closed as indicated in `netstat -ano`. The documentation does not provide any method to unbind a port and the Internet seems to suggest that the only way to close a TCP port is to kill the process which binds to it. But in this case, there is no way to do it because the process is already dead except with a restart which is highly undesirable on phones. Besides, I would like to unbind a port (to bind again instead of binding to another port) at runtime should similar problem occurs. (Using random port is probably better for security but that is another issue.)

So is there a solution for this problem? Shouldn't apps be allowed to close ports it previously bound?

Comment: Calling `DatagramSocket::Dispose()` or `delete myDatagramSocket` should be the way to release the port. If you are using `SocketActivityTrigger`, run your app again, get back the ownership of the socket and then dispose the socket.

Comment: What state does `netstat` show for the port? @kiewic 'Get back the ownership of the socket' is meaningless. The socket has gone, with the old process.

Comment: @EJP `netstat` gives `LISTENING`. Getting back ownership of a socket makes sense in universal app. I will put some more explanation in the description.